# Keep images from breaking to next line without float

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a footer with social media icons. I want the icons arranged in a 3 x 3 grid
like below.

@ @ @

@ @ @

@ @ @

I also want it centered in a div. The issue that I'm running into, is that when I float the elements left to keep them on the same line my

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Doesnt work, and they just align left. I need a solution that will work for mobile since my whole site is responsive.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="d-all m-all" id="mainFooter">
    <div class="d1-d4 m-all" id="socialMedia">
        <div id="centerIcons">
            <img src="images/fb_icon_vi.png"><img src="images/tw_icon_vi.png"><img src="images/in_icon_vi.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d5-d8 m-all" id="contact">
        Contact
    </div>
    <div class="d9-d12 m-all" id="awards">
        awards
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS

```
#mainFooter{
    background-color:black;
    height:250px;
}


#socialMedia{
    background-color:green;
}
    #socialMedia img{
        display:block;


    }

    #centerIcons{
        background-color:yellow;
        width:50%;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        height:75px;
    }
        #centerIcons img{
            margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        }
```

The whole site can be seen [HERE](http://www.voipstreet.com/testSite/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<img>` is a replaced inline element (by default). The image elements sit beside each other like words. Therefore there's no need to change their display type to `block` (as you have done in the live demo).

> I want the icons arranged in a 3 x 3 grid

In order to achieve that, you could wrap each 3 images by a wrapper, and add `text-align: center` to that element to align the inline images horizontally.

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/cuhococo/1/edit)**.

```
<div id="centerIcons">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="images/1.png">
        <img src="images/2.png">
        <img src="images/3.png">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="images/4.png">
        <img src="images/5.png">
        <img src="images/6.png">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="images/7.png">
        <img src="images/8.png">
        <img src="images/9.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: @onTheInternet You are so welcome. Additionally in order to suppress line breaks you could add `white-space: nowrap;` to the wrapper. **[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/cuhococo/2/edit)**.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to something like this, right?

[image]

```
#socialMedia img {
   display: inline-block;
}    
   #centerIcons{
            background-color:yellow;
            width:50%;
            height:75px;
            max-width: 171px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
            #centerIcons img{
               /* nothing is needed */
            }
```

**Explanation:**

`display: inline-block;` will keep as block but not opening a new line

since `#centerIcons` is a DIV element, it is a block element, to make use of centering effect with `margin: 0 auto;` a width control is needed

so `max-width: 171px;` will constraint its width to a maximum of 171px (icon width 57px * 3), you may adjust as you need

**Note:**

About display property, please refer to [W3C's visual formatting model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop).

About box model specification, you may refer to [W3C's box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).

Depends on your browser compatibility plan, max-width does not supported in IE8 below and IE8 have some bugs. For details, you may refer to [online compatibility chart like this](http://caniuse.com/minmaxwh).

If you are using jQuery and really mean to support IE6-8, you may consider using polyfill such as [Scott Jehl's Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)

Edit: I think @Matt Smith's answer is what you want, I may have misinterpreted your meaning. Anyway, for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align: center` to the `#centerIcons {}` rule and `display: inline-block` to your  `#centerIcons img {}` rule:

```
#centerIcons img {
    text-align: center;
}
#centerIcons img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This has the effect I want but aligns the images left